# Kivy 1.9.1 Windows package .spec single exe

Tags: windows, kivy

I want to make a Windows package of my app with most files being in the .exe. According to [Kivy - Create package on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911658/kivy-create-package-on-windows) I installed setuptools 19.2. I'm on Kivy 1.9.1 stable.

According to the instructions on https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html I got the following **working** .spec file:

```
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['..\\foo\\main.py'],
             pathex=['path\\KO-exe'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             hiddenimports=['six','packaging','packaging.version','webbrowser'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='foo',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True , icon='..\\foo\\ko.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('..\\foo\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins )],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='foo')
```

However I end up with a folder with many files, not something I can distribute to other people. So with adding the command `--onefile` and applying the same steps to the .spec file, I get the following **NOT WORKING** .spec:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['..\\foo\\main.py'],
             pathex=['path\\KO-exe'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             hiddenimports=['six','packaging','packaging.version','webbrowser'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz, Tree('..\\foo\\'),
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins )],
          name='foo',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True , icon='..\\foo\\ko.ico')
```

**Error:** .exe only in `build` folder and not in `dist`, and when running: `Error loading Python DLL: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI81162\python27.dll (error code 126)`

### Questions

I've been trying to make all kinds of combinations of the working .spec and the single .spec (adding COLLECT, moving `Tree('..\\foo\\')` around), but to no avail.

- What should I change to have a working single .exe?
- How can I select files/folder to exclude? (what syntax should I use in `Tree()`?)
- I want almost everything inside the .exe, besides data\db\database.db (too slow in a .exe). How do I do this?

### Edit 3

The working .spec file with help From @tito:

```
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
# -*- mode: python -*-
#import pdb
import sys

sys.path += ["..\\foo\\"]

block_cipher = pyi_crypto.PyiBlockCipher(key='1234567890')

#'six','packaging','packaging.version',
a = Analysis(['..\\foo\\main.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\path\\KO-exe'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             
             hiddenimports=[
             'webbrowser',
             '__init__',
             'data.__init__',
             'data.screens.__init__',
             'data.screens.dbmanager',
             'data.screens.db_kv.__init__',
             'data.screens.db_kv.backupsd',
             ],
             
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
             
#pdb.set_trace()
             
# exclusion list
from os.path import join
from fnmatch import fnmatch
exclusion_patterns = (
    join("kivy_install", "data", "images", "testpattern.png"),
    join("kivy_install", "data", "images", "image-loading.gif"),
    join("kivy_install", "data", "keyboards*"),
    join("kivy_install", "data", "settings_kivy.json"),
    join("kivy_install", "data", "logo*"),
    join("kivy_install", "data", "fonts", "DejaVuSans*"),
    join("kivy_install", "modules*"),
    join("Include*"),
    join("sdl2-config"),
    # Filter app directory
    join("personal*"),
    join("sign-apk*"),
    join(".idea*"),
)

def can_exclude(fn):
    for pat in exclusion_patterns:
        if fnmatch(fn, pat):
            return True
            
a.datas = [x for x in a.datas if not can_exclude(x[0])]
a.binaries = [x for x in a.binaries if not can_exclude(x[0])]
# Filter app directory
appfolder = [x for x in Tree('..\\foo\\', excludes=['*.py','*.pyc']) if not can_exclude(x[0])]  

#print(a.zipped_data)

#pdb.set_trace()
            
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='foo',
          debug=True,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True , icon='..\\foo\\ko.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe, appfolder,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins )],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='foo')
```

I wanted to exclude folders and files from my app folder, and thanks tito, through you I figured out how to filter `Tree()` as well.

After getting PyInstaller to exclude files, I'll try running NSIS over the output files.

Comment: For single-exe with NSIS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552659/nsis-after-pyinstaller-kivy-app-cant-find-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imo, i don't know exactly why your application is failing with onefile mode. But because of the implication of using onefile mode from pyinstaller (it will decompress the files every run in a temporary directory), it might be better to do an installer with [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

To select modules to excludes, you can put them in the `excludes` parameters in your `Analysis`:

```
excludes=["pickle", "csv"]
```

To excludes files, i'm usually doing a manual exclusion after analysis / before EXE. Here is an example:

```
# exclusion list
from fnmatch import fnmatch
exclusion_patterns = (
    join("kivy_install", "data", "images", "testpattern.png"),
    join("kivy_install", "data", "images", "image-loading.gif"),
    join("kivy_install", "data", "keyboards*"),
    join("kivy_install", "data", "settings_kivy.json"),
    join("kivy_install", "data", "logo*"),
    join("kivy_install", "data", "fonts", "DejaVuSans*"),
    join("kivy_install", "modules*"),
    join("Include*"),
    join("sdl2-config"),
)

def can_exclude(fn):
    for pat in exclusion_patterns:
        if fnmatch(fn, pat):
            return True
a.datas = [x for x in a.datas if not can_exclude(x[0])]
a.binaries = [x for x in a.binaries if not can_exclude(x[0])]
```

Comment: you used a.binaries in your Collect() directly while i was reassigning it before Exe(). If you wanna use it in the Collect() rule directly, use "binaries=...", not "a.binaries=..."

Comment: I thought the position of a.datas was just for space convenience. I also wanted to filter Tree() and thanks to you I succeeded, see updated answer. Now I can continue with trying NSIS.